# How to convert uint64 values to ArrayBuffers? I've only found the reversal in the link below:

Tags: javascript

How to convert uint64 values to ArrayBuffers? I've only found the reversal in the link below.

Does anyone have an optimum way of two way conversion? both ways. from uint64 to arraybuffers and arraybuffers to uint64

[How to Read 64-bit Integer from an ArrayBuffer / DataView in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103695/how-to-read-64-bit-integer-from-an-arraybuffer-dataview-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

1. Create a [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array/BigUint64Array) with the length you want.
2. Populate it (optional).
3. A reference to the underlying `ArrayBuffer` is in the `.buffer` property.

Every time you change an element of the `BigUint64Array`, the `ArrayBuffer` also changes.

```js
const typedArr = new BigUint64Array(100);

for (let i = 0n; i < typedArr.length; i++)
  typedArr[i] = i;

const arrayBuffer = typedArr.buffer;
```