# get response from servel on ajax call when uploading file with multidata form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm with a little problem on my project.
Hi have several jsp's and Java class. In one jsp i create a form with only a input type="file" and type="submit", then I have an ajax call and send all the formdata to a doPost class on my servel. Then I send that file to the DataBase and it all's go fine, my problem is I want to return the id from the database to the .jsp. I can access and have prints on the doPost to check my key, but cant send it to success function inside the ajax call..
Here's my code, i really apreciate any kind of help, thanks!

```
<form id="uploadDocuments" target="invisible"  method="POST" action="UploadDocumentsAjaxService" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <iframe name="invisible" style="display:none;"></iframe>                    
                    <h3 style="width: 71%;margin-left: 8%;">ANEXAR FICHEIROS:</h3>
                    <h4 style="margin-left: 8%; color: #F7A707" >Escolher ficheiro para anexar: </h4>
                    <input type="file" id="file_input" name="file" size="50" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 8%;"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </form>
```

the I have my Ajax Call:

```
$("#uploadDocuments").submit(function (e) {
        alert(10);
        alert($("#uploadDocuments").attr('action'));
        $.ajax({
            type: $("#uploadDocuments").attr('method'),
            url: $("#uploadDocuments").attr('action'),
            contentType: $("#uploadDocuments").attr( "enctype"),
            data: new FormData($("#uploadDocuments")[0]),
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("submitDocument");
                alert();
                /* key = data;
                addFilesToTable(key); */
                return true;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        $(form).off('submit');
        return false;
        });
```

And then my servlet class:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    ChangeEntityRequestActionBean actionBean = new ChangeEntityRequestActionBean();

    if(!isMultipart)
        return;

    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // Sets the size threshold beyond which files are written directly to
    // disk.
    factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

    // constructs the folder where uploaded file will be stored
    String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + DATA_DIRECTORY;

    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    // Set overall request size constraint
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
    String fileName = "";
    Long documentKey = null;
    String key = "";

    try {
        // Parse the request
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                System.out.println(filePath);
                // saves the file to upload directory
                item.write(uploadedFile);
            }
            documentKey = actionBean.insertDocument(item, fileName);

            System.out.println("Key from DAO ------->>>>>"+documentKey);
            key = String.valueOf(documentKey);

        }

        System.out.println("Key in String from DAO ----->"+key);
        System.out.println();

        out.println("success");
        response.flushBuffer();
    }catch (FileUploadException ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
  } finally {
      out.close();
  }


}
```

All I want is to send the key value to out.println so I can use that value on a jquery function

Comment: send it as json dude.

Comment: I tried to send the key with json and it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line of `doPost()` in your servlet, change the content-type of the response to "application/json".  Then write a JSON string to the output stream.  There are [libraries](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/top-7-open-source-json-binding-providers-available-today.html) available to do this for you, but for something so simple, you can compose the JSON yourself.  This might actually have an advantage because your key is a [java long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320706/javascript-long-integer); treat it as a string and you don't have to worry about how the integer is represented.

```
// replace out.println("success"); with this:
out.print("{\"key\": \"" + key + "\"}");
```

Then in the success callback function, you can access the key as a field of the `data` object.  You'll need to specify the data type in the ajax method (`dataType: 'json'`).

```
success: function (data) {
    var key = data['key'];
    addFilesToTable(key);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It help a bit, thanks! ;). But now it sends the string {\"key\": \"" + key + "\"}" for a file and IE asks if I want so open or save ... And I can't get a way to alert something on my success function, it seemes it never enters there

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would happen, from looking at your code.  Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I just add this three lines and it worked: cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,