# Json result displayed wrong value when shown

Tags: json, json.net, editor, string-formatting, precision

The result returned from webapi shown below

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "TEST 1",
"no": 35797506102858582
}]
```

The value of the "no" property is returned wrongly as **35797506102858584**  when json result displayed. Ex:https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6f97f53689e24222ba931bdeee70f836

What is the cause of the problem ? How can i fix..

Comment: what is your actual question

Comment: @Vivekab What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem parsing and displaying your JSON with [tag:json.net], see https://dotnetfiddle.net/08K3C4   Thus this question seems to have nothing to do with that tag.  I can confirm that the web site https://jsoneditoronline.org/ shows the wrong value for `"no"`.  It has a github page here: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor, so maybe you could report an [issue](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/issues).  Beyond that I think this may be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: [Javascript long integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320706/javascript-long-integer).  If so, you'll need to represent your `id` as a string not an integer.

Comment: @dbc i reproduce the same scenario with Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1. i think there is a bug at this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `no` value inside `double quotes`

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "TEST 1",
"no": "35797506102858582"
}]
```