# Javascript long integer from server is not accurate

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've got an [API](http://api.nemov.org/api/v1/Market/Symbol) which I make a `get` request to fetch data. When i try to save the `Id`, I see Javascript round the last digit of it and it makes my program to break!

I see [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320706/javascript-long-integer) but how can I save **each** `Id` as `string`?

I'm using a global array to store the selected items' data so, anyway to save one attribute of a `JSON` in `string`?

I'm going to have (for example) 3 items and make another `get` request for each `Id`:

```
axios.get(`http://api.nemov.org/api/v1/Market/Symbol/${this.props.ID}`)
```

One of those `Id`s, is: `9481703061634967` but JS convert that to `9481703061634968` so the `get` request is broken!

Any solution?

Comment: `9481703061634967 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` get request isn't broken - that number is too big - why have you mentioned JSON? the API returns XML not JSON

Comment: `how can I save each Id as string` - when you parse the XML, don't change the Id from it's current type (a string, because everything in XML is a string) to integer - then your code won't break the data it gets from the API

Comment: @Bravo - yeah, i mean that i can't make my other request which is dependent on the Id - how can i store that? consider that, that is not a single item, i have an array of objects which every one of them have Id with this long!

Comment: you've shown ZERO code .. .so, I can't tell you which part of your code that parses the XML is breaking the ID - look for parseInt, parseFloat or even a unary + in your code

Comment: i'm using `Axios` so i'm receiving JSON not XML

Comment: you've shown XML, you haven't shown JSON - something must be converting the XML to JSON - it's not the server, it must be your code

Comment: if you mean about the API link, if you use a browser, it will return XML but if you use `Axios` or anything like that, you will get JSON

Comment: To summarize: The serverside can't be changed to return strings instead of integers, `JSON.parse()` cannot be customized to return ints instead of strings, so the only option I can see is a custom parser, which seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: @JonasWilms - hmm... or maybe i can create a new array of Ids (Id is string) and copy every Id when receiving the response immediately - this will work?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/datalanche/json-bignum/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @JonasWilms - can i use that in React Native?

Comment: You can tell Axios to fetch XML, not JSON (`responseType`)...

Comment: just set `'Accept':'application/xml'` request header, and you'll get XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023065/9868239) question:

> Transform the response to string, then apply a repalce with a regex to
>   convert Id field to string type:
>
> ```
> const axios = require("axios");
> axios.get(url, {transformResponse: [data => data]}).then((response) => {
>     let parsed = JSON.parse(response.data.replace(/"Id":(\d+),/g, '"Id":"$1",'))
>     console.log(parsed)
> });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
let strId = this.props.ID.toString();
axios.get(`http://api.nemov.org/api/v1/Market/Symbol/${strId}`)
```

Comment: Not Working! - Consider that this is happening when i fetch data and save the response NOT when i pass the props!