# Javascript - convert an EXTRA LARGE Number to string in JSON before the default parsing

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

As I mentioned in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021331/javascript-long-integer-from-server-is-not-correct), I have problem when getting the response from the server.

I receive an array of objects with these attributes:

```
[{
"Id": 143187001116603,   // VERY big number which I want to convert it to string
"Name": "تملی612",   // string
"Title": "تسهیلات مسکن بانک ملی-اسفند96",   // string
"InsCode": "IRO6MELZ96C1"   // string
},
...
]
```

Any simple way to convert a specified type (`Number`) to `string` in a `JSON` file?

I see the `replacer` argument in `JSON.stringify()` but I have no idea how to use that...

### UPDATE

One of those Ids, is: `9481703061634967` but JS convert that to `9481703061634968`!

### UPDATE

As **Jonas H** said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022699/4565015), JS run the **default parsing** and that's why i lose my real `Id` value!

Any idea?

Comment: `JSON.parse(response)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transform the response to `string`, then apply a repalce with a regex to convert `Id` field to string type:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get(url, { transformResponse: [data => data] }).then(response => {
  let parsed = JSON.parse(response.data.replace(/"Id":(\d+),/g, '"Id":"$1",'));
  console.log(parsed);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you receive the data as a Json string with the numbers inside them, there is no way to preserve the data using JSON.parse. Even if you use the second argument to add a transformation function, it will only be run after the default parsing has parsed the numbers with a loss of information in case of large numbers. You need to manipulate the string directly to wrap the number in quotes using e.g. a regular expression.

You can also use the json-bigint npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint

Comment: Thanks for info - Would you please provide some code? any way to do this before the default parsing?

Comment: Try the link I just added, that's probably better than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks - Can I use this with `Axios`? or I have to use `fetch()` and save the response in `JSONbig`?

Comment: I'm unsure whether axios interceptors or responseTransform can be used before the automatic Json parse step, but you might want to try them out.

Comment: It's working! the `transformResponse` run before automatic JSON parse!

Comment: Glad I could help you out

Answer (score 0):

you can use replacer in  JSON.stringify() like :

```
var obj  = {
"Id": 143187001116603,   // VERY big number which I want to convert it to string
"Name": "تملی612",   // string
"Title": "تسهیلات مسکن بانک ملی-اسفند96",   // string
"InsCode": "IRO6MELZ96C1"   // string
};


function replacer(name, val) {
    // convert Number to string
    if ( val && val.constructor === Number ) {
        return val.toString();
    } else {
        return val; // return as is
    }
};

 JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, 4);
```

// result

```
{
    "Id": "143187001116603",
    "Name": "تملی612",
    "Title": "تسهیلات مسکن بانک ملی-اسفند96",
    "InsCode": "IRO6MELZ96C1"
}
```

Comment: The value of `Id` is changed before... See the **update** please

Comment: @MohamadKh75 this is because of number limit in JavaScript.

Comment: I know and that's why i'm asking for a way to convert it to a `string`

Comment: JavaScript numbers are Double Precision Floats; the largest integer that can be precisely stored is 2^53 (9007199254740992). If you actually need it in a number you have some fun math ahead of you, or you can use a library such as [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js)

Comment: I really don't need that in `Number` format! i just want to save that as `string` before default parsing round it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
  // Filtering out properties
  if (key === 'Id') {
    return value.toString();
  }
  return value;
}

const t = [{
    "Id": 143187001116603, // VERY big number which I want to convert it to string
    "Name": "تملی612", // string
    "Title": "تسهیلات مسکن بانک ملی-اسفند96", // string
    "InsCode": "IRO6MELZ96C1" // string
  },
  {
    "Id": 9481703061634967, // VERY big number which I want to convert it to string
    "Name": "تملی232", // string
    "Title": "تسهیلات مسکن بانک ملی-اسفن216", // string
    "InsCode": "IRO6MSDZ96C1" // string
  }
]
const stringifiedValue = JSON.stringify(t, replacer)
console.log(JSON.parse(stringifiedValue))
```

Try this using replacer callback for JSON.stringify.

Feedbacks welcome.