# jquery $.ajax get not returning correct json

Tags: jquery, json

I have an internal api that I am hitting which returns:

```
[
   {
      "product":{
         "zoho_product_id":3745508000000622066,
         "product_name":"SIP Channels (SIP Select)"
      },
      "product_dependencies":[
         {
            "zoho_product_id":3745508000000622067,
            "product_name":"SIP Access (xxx IP WAN)"
         },
         {
            "zoho_product_id":3745508000000622068,
            "product_name":"SIP Access (xxx Wireless)"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When I use jquery to retrieve the contents of this url:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_dependency/${product_id}/`,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {format : "json"}
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
          console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

The result is incorrect. It looks like when I parse the response from the api it uses the first `zoho_product_id` for all entries, which is incorrect:

[image]

The weird thing is that the raw response text contains the correct id's, think there is a bug possibly when jquery translates the response into a data/json object?
[image]

Comment: it is related not with ajax, but with javascript [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
the number you receive: `3745508000000622068`, is "too big", try to `console.log(3745508000000622068)` and you'll see that the logged value is different

Comment: If you control the API, then convert those IDs to strings before sending them to JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript long integer from server is not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021331/javascript-long-integer-from-server-is-not-accurate)

Comment: Hi @CalvinNunes, yes it does thanks. I have decided to just use a js object instead of hashmap and it seems to be working well