# How do I work with 64-bit integers in the Foundry UI?

Tags: palantir-foundry

When working datasets that contain 64-bit integers in, the numbers are often truncated in the UI which makes them difficult to work with.

Why is this the case, and how can I work around this?

As an example, in my dataset I have an ID column of type Long. One such value might be `8223372036854775808`.

In this instance:

1. the Foundry UI (e.g. when previewing a dataset) will display the value as `8223372036854776000`.
2. If I use Contour to filter for rows where the ID columns is equals to `8223372036854775808`, I get a warning:

```
The following filter value is too large and will not produce correct results: 8223372036854775808
```

3. Copy/pasting the value also results in the value being truncated, making it hard to reference the ID in another workflow (e.g. to copy it into a form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Foundry UI utilises JavaScript, and in JavaScript there is no way to represent 64-bit integers, as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320706/javascript-long-integer).

This not only applies to columns of type Long, but also any data type which might contain 64-bit integers (such as Arrays, or Structs).

Usually the best way to interact with these numbers this large in the Foundry UI is to convert them into Strings first.