# is it possible try to convert the data type when using rust serde json

Tags: json, rust

I am using rust serde json to deserialize some json string, for some reason(the front javascript could not handle the i64 data type, more information from here:[Javascript long integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320706/javascript-long-integer)), the server side convert the i64 to string by default. this default action make the rust deserialize data failed, this is the minimal demo to show this issue:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let text_response = "{\"id\":\"1\"}";
    let resp_result = serde_json::from_str::<RdUserInfo>(&text_response);
    if let Err(e) = resp_result {
        print!("{}", e);
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct RdUserInfo {
    pub id: i64,
}
```

this is the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
```

I was wonder is it possible to try to convert the string to i64, if failed, throw the error. I have already tried like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct RdUserInfo {
    #[serde(try_from = "String")]
    pub id: i64,
}
```

did not work. BTW, the error shows that:

```
invalid type: string "1", expected i64 at line 1 column 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_from` works off of the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait, but for mostly historical reasons `TryFrom<&str>` and `TryFrom<String>` are not really things, the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait exists instead.

Sadly unlike `TryFrom` serde doesn't have a hook for `FromStr`, so your options are [manual implementation of deserialize](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/908) or [using `serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/derive.DeserializeFromStr.html).

Or [taking a time machine to whenever specialisation gets implemented and there's a blanket implementation of `TryFrom<&str>` for `FromStr`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53167).

Comment: Even if we end up with specialization some day, it is really unclear what it'll include, and at least the current RFC does not allow such specialization.